# How to specify template in KeystoneJS using Handlebars?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, keystonejs

I'm trying to set the template/layout for one specific view (not change the default template). Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.

In the view controller (in my case: routes\views\index.js) you can pass options to the view.render() function.

I changed

```
view.render('index');
```

to

```
view.render('index', {layout:'landing'});
```

What really threw me though was I needed to restart the application for this to take effect.